# Handling KeyCode/KeyChar events in Windows Form TextBox Control

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have various input textboxes on my form. And based on entries made in each of the input textboxes, I update the display textbox. However, using AppendText message of textbox. I have my input textboxes set to accept only numeric values. So for each character inputted correctly, I update the display Textbox. Problem I have is when user selects Key.Back or Key.Delete, what I would like to do is do a Delete of last character in the display textbox, but I am yet to get this right. How do I delete the last character in the string that is contained in a TextBox using AppendText() or any of the utility functions available in that control please?

```
If (e.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Back)) Then
                txtDisplay.Text -= 1
                txtDisplay.Update()
                ElseIf (Not (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Or Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Or (e.KeyChar = "."))) Then
                    e.Handled = True
                Else
                    txtDisplay.AppendText(e.KeyChar)
                End If
```

Comment: That's not the only problem you have.  Type Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C while you look at this page.  Go back to your program, right-click the text box and select Paste.  Use the Validating event instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use this  in `KeypPress` event handler of `txtDisplay`

```
    If e.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Back) Then
        If txtDisplay.Text.Length > 0 Then 
            txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text.Substring(0, txtDisplay.TextLength - 1)
            txtDisplay.SelectionStart = txtDisplay.Text.Length
        End If
    ElseIf (Not (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Or Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Or (e.KeyChar = "."))) Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
```

Comment: What does this magic code do? How does it solve the problem he's experiencing? How is it different from the code he already has?

Comment: @Cody Gray : I'm my workstation i just tried his code. It deducts 1 when ever i press `bake space`. Add gets any digit twice. Why don;t you try both **magic codes**

Comment: Try it yourself. **NB :** I'm using **VS 2010**

Comment: The point is that your answer is incomplete without an explanation.

Comment: @CodyGray : What explanation do you want?